# For a Gaussian likelihood, how to choose a prior that biases the MAP estimates away from zero (opposite of L2 regularization)

Tags: bayesian, normal-distribution, modeling

Suppose that $x\in R^1$,  $y\in [-30,30]$ and $P(y|x) \sim N(y; x,\sigma_x)$. If I were to choose $P(x) \sim N(x;0,\sigma_p)$ and observe a single $y$ value, my MAP estimate of $x$ would be
$$\frac{\frac{y}{\sigma_x}}{\frac{1}{\sigma_x}+\frac{1}{\sigma_p}}$$ or
$$ \frac{y}{1+\frac{\sigma_x}{\sigma_p}}$$
since the denominator is always a constant greater than 1, the estimate is always the $y$ value divided by a constant that biases it towards 0. Is there a way for me to choose a prior such that the MAP estimate would be some form of $y$ that is biased away from 0?

 
e.g. If $y$ is -5, MAP estimate of $x$ should be a bit more negative than -5. If  $y$ is 5, MAP estimate of $x$ should be a bit more positive than 5.


Also, the MAP estimate should have an analytical expression.


Much thanks in advance!! Also, the more options the better!


edit:

1. This should work for any value of $y$ and the prior needs to be chosen before seeing $y$.
2. sorry made a mistake,instead of $y\in R^1$, $y\in [-30,30]$. As long as it's bounded by a negative number and a positive number it would work fine.

Comment: Why do you need such prior? What is the purpose?

Comment: But why do you want the values to be "away from zero"? What do you mean by that? You want them to be as big as possible? Why?

Comment: By away from 0, I meant that the MAP estimate of x should be y multiplied by some constant or values that is greater than 1 regardless of the value of y. Let me know what other information I should include. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In general (i.e., for nonzero prior means), the posterior mean in the normal-normal location model is
$$
\frac{1/\tau^2}{1/\tau^2+n/\sigma^2}\mu_0+\frac{n/\sigma^2}{1/\tau^2+n/\sigma^2}\bar{x}
$$
for a prior mean $\mu_0$, a prior variance $\tau^2$, a population variance (assumed known here) $\sigma^2$ and a sample size $n$ (so notation is slightly different from yours, see https://www2.bcs.rochester.edu/sites/jacobslab/cheat_sheet/bayes_Normal_Normal.pdf.

Hence, the posterior mean is a weighted average of sample mean and prior mean. So if you want to the posterior mean be be further *away* from zero than the sample mean, you would need to pick $\mu_0>\bar x$ if $\bar x>0$ and $\mu_0<\bar x$ if $\bar x<0$.

But, since you should pick your prior *before* seeing the data, it is not clear how you would achieve that in general.

Comment: Indeed, I would need the prior to bias estimates away from 0 regardless of the value of y, so this unfortunately wouldn't work. Thanks though!

Comment: Of course, the larger you pick $|\mu_0|$, the higher the chance that the posterior is affected in the desired fashion.